# Android scratch View 2 Layers

Tags: imageview, android-image, effects

I'm using [Android-WScratchView](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView) to implement a `scratch` effect in my app.

What my app does is a "cleaning" effect. I have a `picture` of a clean t-shirt and another `picture` of the same t-shirt but dirty (with some mud).

[Android-WScratchView](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView) works great for the normal case, a background `Image` (clean t-shirt) and an `overlay` Image (dirty t-shirt).

The problem is now, I need to add a second overlay `Image`, which is a "less" dirty t-shirt so the user has to "clean" the t-shirt in 2 steps.

Once the first layer has been erased, I need to be able to erase the second layer but only where it is visible.

I've implemented it using 2 `WScratchView` objects, one behind another, like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shirt_clean" />

<com.winsontan520.WScratchView
    xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scratch_view_layer_1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    wsv:antiAlias="true"
    wsv:revealSize="20dp"
    wsv:scratchDrawable="@drawable/shirt_less_dirty"
    wsv:scratchable="true" />

<com.winsontan520.WScratchView
    xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scratch_view_layer_2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    wsv:antiAlias="true"
    wsv:revealSize="20dp"
    wsv:scratchDrawable="@drawable/shirt_dirty"
    wsv:scratchable="true" />
```

The problem is that after the "most dirty" `layer` is "erased" (it gets transparent) I cannot delete the "less dirty" `layer` because the second `layer` is getting the `onTouch` event.

My idea is parsing somehow the `onTouch` event through the second `WScratchView` to the first one. But still would have the problem that I don't know which area has already been deleted and which not.

I would appreciate any help, also a different way to implement it will be accepted.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do  with the graphical language Scratch